# Duda sobre colaboradores en GitHub

Tags: git, github, repositorio

soy colaborador en un repositorio de GitHub, pero a la hora de meterme en los colaboradores del proyecto (dentro de Insights, en contributors) no salgo, el caso es que ya he realizado varios commits y tengo permisos sobre el, sabeis a que se puede deber, aclarar que tampoco me salen los commits en mi propio perfil, por ejemplo, hoy he realizado 2 commits y en mi perfil no me aparece ninguno de los 2.

Comment: Pensaría que hay alguna diferencia entre el correo de los commits y el de la cuenta de github.

Comment: lo comprobé antes de realizar la pregunta y son los mismo, tanto el de git en mi ordenador, como en github

Comment: y segun tu donde salen los colaboradores?

Comment: @RuslanLópez dentro de Insights, en contributors, ya lo solucioné. Gracias de todas formas.